# Artifact missing error when I add jar file in Maven

Tags: maven, artifact

I use maven to manage my jar files in my project.Firstly ,I download the org.apache.mrunit of version 0.8.0-incubating.But I find that it is not compatiable with my project so I remove it and what to re-download a 1.0.0 version.But I cannot download the version 1.0.0. Error message in eclipse is:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MapReducer: Could not
> resolve dependencies for project
> org.MapReducer1.0.0:MapReducer:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
> org.apache.mrunit:mrunit:jar:1.0.0 in
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

But when I search mrunit online ,I can get the version list:[image]

But when I search it in my pom.xml of eclipse , I can only get the version 0.8.0-incubating:
[image]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried setting dependency to 1.0.0 version and building it from console?

Comment: Based on what i can see you are using `-SNAPSHOT` versions which are not in Maven central. Any special reason why you use SNAPSHOT versions instead of released ones?

Comment: @khmarbaise What's your meaning?Of cource ,MapReducer is my project name, it is of cource snapshot version.What should I do?Even I create a brand new project, I can not search the mrunit 1.0.0.

Comment: @Deltharis Would youplease give me more detailed instruction?Thank you.

Comment: @Deltharis.I am using eclipse IDE and have build it.

Comment: What I meant is - to avoid eclipse-plugin-centric weird issues you could check whether standalone maven installation builds your project. That is, installing maven (if you didn't yet) and punching "mvn clean install" in the console

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a rather old question, but I just encountered the same problem. I resolved it by adding a classifier, as indicated on the [Apache MRUnit Tutorial page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MRUNIT/MRUnit+Tutorial)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <classifier>hadoop2</classifier> 
</dependency>
```

User hadoop1 if you are using an older version of hadoop.